# How to connect to VM instance while /home directory lost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mount

For some reasons, the boot disk of my VM instance was no longer enough to use. And I wanted to move the whole `/home` directory to the new disk.

I followed the GCP guide to create and mount the disk to `/data/diks-1/`. Then I moved `/home` to `/data/disk-1/home`, and create a soft link to `/home`. Everything worked well just like what I expected.

However, I forgot to modify the `fstab` file for automatic mounting. And I **restarted** the VM instance...

Now, I cannot connect the instance via ssh, and have no idea about how to solve this. The whole `/data/disk-1` directory must be unmounted, which include settings of all users. Are there any ways to remount the disk ?

Comment: Create a startup script to mount the disk. Then log in and modify fstab. I wrote an article that shows various recovery methods for a different problem that should help you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley. Thanks for your reply. I did try the method 1 with following value, but still could not log in with ssh. Also tried the method 2, it responded "Login incorrect". Could you please give me more help for this ?
`#!/bin/bash
mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /data/disk-1
ln -s /data/disk-1/home/ home`

Comment: Enable serial console and boot with it. When the boot loader asks for kernel parameters, add init=/bin/bash. So nothing will be executed, just /bin/bash. That will give you a prompt (no password as login wont be executed either). Then you can remount / read-writable, e.g. with the command mount -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /. Then you can do your changes.

Comment: To know what is going wrong, I need to see the error. The Serial Console can provide the boot logs. Edit your question with the script that you tried and the error result so that I can read it.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, I found out that I typed the wrong disk name into the startup-script. Thanks for your help and apologize for my newbie behavior.

Comment: Please post an answer with your solution. Being able to recover from broken instances can be a life safer.

Answer (score 2):

Followings are the ways I re-mount the disk. Hope these could help anyone has the same problem like me.

1. Click the `EDIT` button on the VM instance page.
2. Click the `Enable connecting to serial ports` checkbox.
3. Click `SAVE` button
4. Build startup-script through the `gcloud command` [Google Doc.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux)
   (I used the console to build it, like @John Hanley's article wrote. But the UI seemed changed.)
5. Key = `startup-script`, Value =

> #! /bin/bash mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /data/disk-1

6. Reboot the VM instance, and you can ssh to instance now.
7. Edit `fstab` after login and remove the `startup-script` then.